# problem with including a model

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I try to include a model in my world file, I get the following error in ROS-fuerte.

```
Error [SystemPaths.cc:262] cannot load file [models/angen_empty.model]in GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH[/home/angenuser/ros_workspace/angen_gazebo/Media/models]
Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Entity: line 2: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
Error [parser_deprecated.cc:1365] Could not parse the xml
Entity: line 2: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
Error [parser_deprecated.cc:1307] Could not parse the xml
Error [parser.cc:263] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [parser.cc:500] Unable to read file[]
Error [parser.cc:557] Error reading element
Error [parser.cc:557] Error reading element
Error [parser.cc:340] Unable to parse sdf element[gazebo]
Error [parser.cc:263] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [Server.cc:196] Unable to read sdf file[/home/angenuser/ros_workspace/angen_cognitive_environment/angen_gazebo/worlds/try.world]
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 6314, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo -u /home/angenuser/ros_workspace/angen_cognitive_environment/angen_gazebo/worlds/try.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/angenuser/.ros/log/dfdc436c-909c-11e2-9418-dc0ea13f6144/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/angenuser/.ros/log/dfdc436c-909c-11e2-9418-dc0ea13f6144/gazebo-2*.log
```

I attached the following code to the empty.world

```
<model name='angen_model' static='1'>
      <origin pose='0 0 0 0 0 0'/>
      <include filename='angen_empty.model'/>
</model>
```

I recently converted the .model file I am using to the new format using gzsdf recently. I works well as .world file but when I remove the world tags and use just the model, I get the errors.

Is this the problem with gazebo or am I doing a mistake ? Can someone tell a proper way to add a .model file to a world.

Thanks,
Prasanna

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1940/problem-with-including-a-model/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/247/prasanna.kumar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2989/prasad/) on 2016-12-28**:
For people who are looking for information, I had to convert my xacro file to URDF (using xacro.py) and include it as mentioned in [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6568/uri-paths-to-packages-in-the-sdf-model-file/?answer=15102#post-id-15102).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

You did not load the model correctly, try it like this in your .world file:

```
<world>
...
    <include>
        <uri>model://my_model</uri>
        <pose>0.3 0.5 0.9 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
</world>
```

If it doesn't work, make sure that you have your GAZEBO PATHS set correctly. Or just add the .model file to ~/.gazebo/models folder.

If you still have trouble ask for more info.

UPDATE!!!
an example of setting the paths (plugin, model, resource):

```
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=~/<path>/my_package_example/lib:${GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH}

export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=~/<path>/my_package_example/models:${GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH}

export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=~/<path>/my_package_example/models:${GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH}
```

Cheers, Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-30**:
Hey Andrei, have you gotten this to work for models outside the ~/.gazebo/models folder?  My model is being recognized by Gazebo -- I can insert it from the "insert" menu.  But trying to  it in a world file produces:
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:373] Unable to download model[model://iri_wam]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:373] Unable to download model[model://iri_wam]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://iri_wam]

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-30**:
Hey Ben, you get the error because you did not have the paths set to your models outside of the .gazebo folder. Check the updated answer I wrote some examples of how to set them, just add those lines to the ~/.bashrc file and don't forget to source it after. Hope it works, Cheers

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-30**:
I'm pretty sure my paths are set correctly because I can insert the model from within Gazebo. Should the  include any indication of the database name, or just the model, or a path to the model?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-01**:
It is weird that by drag and drop it works and the other way it does not. In my world file I have like  just as in the answer: model://my_model . In which version of gazebo are you getting this error? Do you also have your model.config file set right? Maybe that also plays a role?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-01**:
Is your my_model in a the ~/.gazebo directory or elsewhere?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-02**:
it is elsewhere

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-02**:
Is your database.config in models or `my_package_example`?
Also, are you storing your plugin .so files in the database lib directory, or in a separate directory for each model?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-04**:
I did not find any `database.config` file, or you meant the models `.config` file, I have that for every model in a separate folder, ex: `my_package/models/model1/model.config` ,  `my_package/models/model2/model.config`, the plugins library files are all in the `my_package/lib` folder

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-06**:
Ah. Got it.  The problem was that I was assuming my_model corresponded to the model name in the model.config file.  Instead, as you probably know, it refers to the folder that the model resides in.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-06**:
BTW, the database.config file is now "suggested" in the user manual.  I'm not too sure what, if anything, it does. http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__models__database.html

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/879/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-02**:
Wow.  I was using the "model name" tag defined inside the SDF file, but I needed to use the folder name.  That was not obvious.  What does the SDF file even contain the "model name" tag if it is not used?